# Error with api version when deleting volume

Tags: python, sdk, openstack

In a python script I want to delete several Openstack objects like instances and volumes. I have no issue with handling instances, but when it comes to volumes I have the following error:

`openstack.exceptions.HttpException: HttpException: 406: Client Error for url https://my.api.com/v3, Version 3.60 is not supported by the API. Minimum is 3.0 and maximum is 3.59.`

According to the API the version in use is the 3.13.

In the `openstack.connect()` method I have tried to set version variables such as `identity_api_version` or `app_version` according to what is said in the [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org//openstacksdk/latest/doc-openstacksdk.pdf), without success. Shall I use a different sdk, perhaps Cinder ?

```
openstack.connect(
  auth_url=auth_url,
  auth_type=auth_type,
  application_credential_id=cred_id, 
  application_credential_secret=cred_secret, 
  identity_api_version='3'
)
```

I have read about "microversion" in the documentation, but I do not see how to set it nor why is it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to remove the `force=true` parameter from the following deleting command:

```
conn.block_storage.delete_volume(__volume_id__)
```

I guess our Openstack API does not handle this parameter in its current version.